# How to enable kibana at startup

Tags: init.d, elasticsearch, kibana

I just downloaded kibana-4.3 tar file , extract it and it works fine. But i want to enable the service at system startup and i got the error by using chkconfig command:

```
    service kibana does not support chkconfig
```

Any workaround?

Comment: What is the OS Version ?

Comment: it is `centos6`

Answer (score 0):

Not nice but just a workaround: you may set in crontab a line similar to

```
@reboot /command/to/bin/start/kibana
```

You should use crontab of the user who owns kibana installation.